# Swift roundf not working with float value

Tags: ios, swift, rounding

```
let amount:Float = 2.235
print("\(roundf(self.amountTax * 100) / 100)")
```

it returns 2.23

but it should be 2.24

Comment: Try `print(amount.debugDescription)` and you'll see the problem ...

Comment: Also have a look at [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

The result is `2.23` because `amount * 100` is `223.5` and the rounding of that is `223` (because `2.235` probably has no exact representation, but is something like `2.234999999999`) , and divided by 100 it results in `2.23`.

You may want to use the `ceilf` unction instead:

```
print("(ceilf(amount * 100) / 100)")
```

This playground result may give you more understanding:
[image]

Comment: `223.5` has an exact representation as Float, but `2.235` hasn't.

Comment: but if amount is "1.4312" its return 1.44, it should be 1.43 for two decimal